# Xcode - Add hyperlink to email

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, email, hyperlink

In some apps you can email straight from the app. I have seen Flipboard, you can email an article to a friend and inside the email is hyperlinked text like this:

Sent via [Flipboard](http://www.apple.com)

So it directs you to the page with a click of the text. How can I do this? I do not want to add the link as part of the message body as it is very messy and ugly... I would prefer this clickable text way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `MFMailComposeViewController` has a method called 
`setMessageBody:isHTML:`.
Here the important thing is `isHTML`.
Doing a link in HTML is quite simple : `<a href=myURL>LinkName</a>`.