# iOS - Is it possible to add clickable urls and also add an attachment in a 3rd party mail client?

Tags: html, ios, hyperlink, href, mailto

From iOS app, trying to open a mail client (other than iOS mail), and send a message with clickable links. Is it possible to send the message with clickable links and a file attachment?

We tried using mailto which doesn't seem to allow clickable links and attachments. I was wondering if there is another method to achieve this. Note that we can not use MFMailComposeViewController because we want to let the user use a different mail client such as outlook.

As a reference, here is the code. The link in the mail body isn't clickable.

- (NSString *)mailTofunction:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message recipients:(NSArray<NSString *> *)recipients BCCRecipients:(NSArray<NSString *> *)BCCRecipients {

  NSString *mailto = @"mailto:";
  NSString *recipient = recipients.firstObject;

  if (0 < recipient.length) {
  mailto = [mailto stringByAppendingString:recipient];
  }
  if (0 < title.length) {
  mailto = [mailto stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?subject=%@", title]];
  }

  NSMutableArray<NSString *> *BCC;

  if (1 < recipients.count) {
  BCC = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:recipients];
  [BCC removeObjectAtIndex:0];
  [BCC addObjectsFromArray:BCCRecipients];
  }

  if (0 < BCC.count) {
  NSString *BCCString = [BCC componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
  mailto = [mailto stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&bcc=%@", BCCString]];
  }

  NSString *bodyText =@"";
  bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@""];
  bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@""];
  bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@"<a     href="http://www.devaski.com">My blog"];
  bodyText = [bodyText stringByAppendingString:@""];

  NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[bodyText dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
  NSString *plainString = attributedString.string;
  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
  NSString *emailBody = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:plainString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [plainString length]) withTemplate:@""];
  mailto = [mailto stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&body=%@", emailBody]];
  return mailto;
  }

**output**

For example. Myblog is displayed in Outlook without any clickable links. Is it possible to add a clickable link [sample outlook message (https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6QlC.jpg)

Comment: What you want is easily supported using `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't want to close the question for duplicate, but I wanted to have the automatic message see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304431/xcode-add-hyperlink-to-email

Comment: You are using `mailto:` to open another client. I would have suggested to put HTML in the `body` parameter, but it all depends on how interpret the receiving app, and I guess it doesn't allow it?

Comment: @HangarRash MFMailComposeView Controller class works fine with the Apple mail app and doesn’t work with third-party mail clients like Gmail and Outlook.

Comment: @pbjs `MFMailComposeView` works with whatever mail accounts you have setup on the device. It doesn't use any specific client.

Comment: @HangarRash This is not true actually. MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail returns false if default iOS mail is not set on device. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66379220/2197292

Comment: @HangarRash , MFMailComposeViewController does not work even after changing the default mail to Outlook.